# Tried flashing Xiaomi 11 Lite 5G but now it doesn't start

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, boot-loop, xiaomi

I attempted to flash my Xiaomi 11 Lite 5G device with the intention of rooting it. Following instructions from a random individual on YouTube, I used Magisk to install a `boot.img` file using platform tools. Prior to this, I had used MiUnlock to unlock the bootloader. As my PC didn't recognize my cellphone initially, I installed new drivers to establish a connection.

Upon restarting the device, it entered into a cycle of rebooting without progressing past the MIUI logo. Eventually, it froze at the logo, and even when I connected the charger while it was turned off, the battery percentage did not display; instead, it immediately jumped to the MIUI logo and froze again. Despite extensive searching, I have been unable to find any solutions to this specific error. Interestingly, it doesn't appear to be a complete freeze; rather, it seems to be stuck in a sort of safe mode, as now it consistently boots into fastboot mode.

I have attempted to flash the original ROM (which I downloaded) back onto the device, but it seems as though the connection is being interrupted once the flashing process begins. Unfortunately, none of the button combinations seem to work, so accessing recovery mode is currently impossible.

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
C:\Users\andre\Desktop\platform-tools>fastboot devices
468d0968         fastboot

C:\Users\andre\Desktop\platform-tools>fastboot flash boot "C:\Users\andre\Desktop\boot.img"
```

[image]

Comment: You wrote that installing the original ROM fails. Please add the flash command and the full output as text into your question.

Comment: As @Robert said, we would need a lot more information to even try to help, but honestly although Magisk works well in many cases, it isn't hard to find stories of it totally bricking devices either. I am also unclear as to the state of the device, can you access fastboot at this point or not?

Comment: When I turn on the device, it shows the fastboot screen, which initially seemed like a straightforward issue to resolve. However, when I attempted to execute a command, the device appeared as disconnected on the PC. I speculated that perhaps running the command first and then connecting the device might yield different results.

After installing the original boot.img and subsequently flashing the original ROM, I was pleased to find that it worked! This approach successfully resolved the issue.

This was the tutorial by the way
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8chR9dooc4&t=721s

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider posting it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed but even encouraged](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!